# Wine application doesn't automatically start after login on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, autostart

On Linux Mint 19 (all "dot" versions), there is an option to add "Start-up applications".

There, I've added the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/thunderbird &

sleep 2

export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable &

sleep 2

export DISPLAY=:0.1
env WINEPREFIX="/home/<user>/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/<user>/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++.lnk &
```

The goal of the script is simple:

- Start Thunderbird on the 1st display
- Start Google Chrome on the 1st display
- Start Notepad++ on the 2nd display

Everything works fine, except that Notepad++ doesn't start.

What I've tried so far:

- Change the order - Simply stopped everything from working
- Reduce the `sleep` time - Doesn't change the behaviour
- Check the logs - Can't find anything (using [`gnome-system-log`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Attic/GnomeUtils) and the included log viewer) about the file being executed or startup programs
- Run the command directly in the shell - Works flawlessly
- Change `#!/usr/bin/env sh` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` - Doesn't change the behaviour

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Does the command line for **Notepad++** work outside the script? Do you have a .desktop file for it?

Comment: "Run the command directly in the shell - Works flawlessly" <-- yup, and yup. That's where I took the command from. From the .desktop file.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was harder than I thought.

The problem was simple: it was the `export DISPLAY=:0.1` that caused the issue.
This is an attempt of the 3rd item in the list: Start Notepad++ on the **2nd display**.

After digging, I found the following post: [Window placement when switching to multiple monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96066/window-placement-when-switching-to-multiple-monitors) (Which links to https://icyrock.com/blog/tag/xdotool/).

In the end, my file now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

env WINEPREFIX="/home/<user>/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/<user>/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++.lnk &

sleep 1

export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/thunderbird &

sleep 1

export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable &

sleep 3

# move to 2nd monitor
# https://icyrock.com/blog/tag/xdotool/
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96066/window-placement-when-switching-to-multiple-monitors

wid=`xdotool search --name Notepad++|head -1`
max_state=`xprop -id $wid _NET_WM_STATE`

wmctrl -ir $wid -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
eval `xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell $wid`

new_x=1600
if [[ "$X" -ge "$new_x" ]]; then
  new_x=0
fi

xdotool windowmove $wid $new_x $Y
if [ -z "${max_state/*_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_*/}" ]; then
  wmctrl -ir $wid -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
fi

xdotool windowraise $wid
```

And everything is working fine now.

Notepad++ is now the first one to start, to give it time to initialize, and then moved to the 2nd display.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar on my Mint PC, although I run this script manually after I login. I found it was easier to use **xdg-open** with the .desktop files; that way, if the command ever changed, my script would still work. Also notice that I do not need to specify back-grounding of the command (with the &):

```
#!/bin/bash

#### This script configures my desktop and other settings ####

SYSTEM_DIR=/usr/share/applications
USER_DIR=$HOME/.local/share/applications

#### Start my preferred programs ####
xdg-open $SYSTEM_DIR/google-chrome.desktop
xdg-open $USER_DIR/org.gnome.Evolution.desktop
xdg-open $SYSTEM_DIR/homebank.desktop
xdg-open $USER_DIR/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.desktop
xdg-open $USER_DIR/virt-manager.desktop
xdg-open $USER_DIR/rhythmbox.desktop
xdg-open $SYSTEM_DIR/FAHControl.desktop
#### End start preferred programs ####
```

You may want to throw in a minor delay at the beginning of the script, in case it takes your system a bit to finish logging in.

Comment: I will test this out and vote accordingly in 8-9 hours. I do have a 10 second delay before it starts. I will try this approach and give you feedback.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. It simply opened the .desktop file in the text editor. But I've managed it.